# electron double slit experiment manipulating interference pattern

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, double-slit-experiment, interference

[image]

Let us suppose we can change the magnetic field and the charge on the interference surface like shown in the picture.
Would it be possible to move our interference pattern along the y-axis by changing the magnetic field and by changing the charge the distance between the peaks? 
Since we can describe an electron as a wave $\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$ by increasing the charge its momentum would get smaller causing the wavelength to increase.
Furthermore, we know that the distance between the peaks is correlated with its wavelength

Comment: Perhaps it is related to Aharonov-Bohm effect?

Comment: Magnetic field i understand here. Charge i dont understand  woulfnt you have a current in your diagramm? (Or if the screen is non conducting, the potentiometer doesnt have a function)

Comment: @lalala I feared that I would mess the circuit up. Here is my idea: I wanted to slow down the electrons before reaching the detecting surface by making it the same charge. The potentiometer should have had the function to regulate how much negative charge that surface can hold

Comment: Given that in an electron microscope one can happily manipulate the diffraction pattern using the various lenses in the system, of course you can. Now, you will have to calculate the trajectories, but that is a solved problem in general.